# How do I present repeated, variable length text in the detail section of an RDLC report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I need to present the following structure in an RDLC report:

```
assessment->outcome->section->question
```

Each of these has four string fields, v.i.z. Title, Text, Notes, and Feedback, with the all but Title being long, variable length text, from a paragraph to a page long. My basic structure is to use'question' for the detail section, with groupings for others, but all over I need to have a textbox report control that will expand to fill its content, all the while being civil about page breaks etc.

I assume a List type Tablix will suffice here, but how do I get my textboxes to expand for their content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather silly question, but the rdlc report TextBox control has CanGrow and CanShrink options, which address this need perfectly.